# Странное поведение include

Tags: php

Есть файл конфига, который возвращает массив значений. Содержимое:

```
<?php return (array ());
```

В классе работы с конфигами, подключаю этот файл и получаю его значение так:

```
$arr = include($full_path);
```

Потом стоит проверка `if(!is_array($arr))...` и в случае если это не массив - выбрасывается исключение.

Возникла странная проблема. На корректное содержимое конфига, однажды я получил исключение. Я проверил файл конфига, он в порядке.

Ошибка возникает тогда, когда выполняется сохранение конфига. Если очень быстро обновить страницу, в одной из итераций получится выбить ошибку. Без сохранения ошибка кажется не возникает.

Сохраняю конфиг функцией `file_put_contents`. Конечно я сразу же подумал что проблема в `LOCK_EX`, но **это не так**! Я убирал этот параметр, ошибка хоть и появлялась реже, она осталась и несколько раз мне удалось её отловить.

Если ДО строчки с проверкой `if(!is_array($arr))...` вставить `var_dump(file_get_contents($full_path))`, ошибку отловливать не получается (у меня не получилось во всяком случае, думаю файл ждет загрузки, а инклуд нет - это основная догадка). Сама же переменная `$arr` содержит 1, если её вызвать до выброса исключения, что говорит о том что файл "успешно" подключен.

Обратите внимание на то, что ошибка возникает после быстрого обновления страницы и не сразу. Я пробовал до инклуда вставлять условие с is_readable, оно вообще ни разу не выдало false.

Учтите, сохранение проходит без проблем. Учтите, ошибка проявляется не каждый раз, и не имеет четкого триггера для вызова, поймать её можно обновляя страницу много раз и быстро (ну или зажав f5), при этом время зажатия не определено.

**Если кто-то знает в чем причина такого поведения, помогите найти решение.**

Моя задача, избавиться от ошибки. Если это невозможно, то хотя бы найти способ выбрасывать конкретную ошибку вроде "файл сейчас недоступен для подключения"

[Код класса и конфига](http://www.paste.org/85350)

Comment: *It's important to understand that LOCK_EX will not prevent reading the file unless you also explicitly acquire a read lock (shared locked) with the PHP 'flock' function.* - со страницы http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php Другими словами, текущей защиты недостаточно, чтобы предотвратить чтение в середине записи.

Comment: @etki "текущей", это какой? Нужно выполнить fclose?

Comment: @etki заменил file_put_contents на последовательность fopen, fwrite, fclose и ничего не изменилось

Comment: LOCK_EX блокирует файл для записи, а include не знает ни о какой блокировке. Так что если "очень быстро обновлять", то такой конфликт - нормальная ситуация.

Comment: @vitidev как я уже сказал, никакой блокировки не существует. Если убрать параметр блокировки, ничего не меняется.

Comment: @TryCatch вы бы все-таки дошли до документации. Вы успешно защищаете свой файл от конкурентной записи, но не производите никаких движений для того, чтобы защитить еще и чтение. При чтении надо ровно так же брать лок.

Comment: @etki о чем вы говорите? Я вообще не устанавливаю параметра, отвечающего за блокировку прав к файлу на время работы с ним. По умолчанию никакой защиты от одновременного доступа к файлу нет.

Comment: Так в этом и суть - надо защитить от чтения файл!

Comment: @Aid и как это сработает? На сколько я понимаю, так: я ставлю защиту от чтения, теперь при быстром обновлении страницы, я буду все так же получать периодические ошибки, но теперь логически обоснованные, потому что я попал в те самые милисекунды в которые файл все ещё заблокирован предыдущей операцией. Если я не прав, поправьте меня, объясните почему установка блокировки на чтение, должна помочь при как раз таки попытке прочитать этот самый файл в новом потоке (я имею в виду перезагрузку страницы)

Comment: @Aid попробовал с `flock($fp, LOCK_SH)` и в конструкторе проверять `is_readable`, ничего не изменилось и никак это, ожидаемо, не помогает.

Comment: В пхп блокировка рекомендательная - кто хочет, тот и используети нет никакого запрета чтения/записи, тем кто не использует. include не использует блокировку. А значит если проблема в конкурентном чтении, то пишите во временный файл и потом используйте rename - он атомарный.

Comment: @vitidev прочтите хотя бы вопрос. Я на что вы "ответили"

Comment: Вопрос  я еще вчера перед сном читал. И после сна не сильно он изменился. И я указал в своем ответе на что я ответил. Так что я высказал свое мнение на то, что написано в вопросе и придерживаюсь его.

Comment: @vitidev оформите в виде ответа про временный файл и rename

Answer (score 1):

В php используется рекомендательная блокировка. Защита файла от конкурентного доступа работает только если **все** писатели и читатели ипользуют в доступе LOCK_(EX|SH). 
Те, кто не использует флаги LOCK_(EX|SH), будут бесконтрольно писать и читать в любой момент.

В php с этим плохо. `file(), include, require` и так далее - не используют блокировку, даже `file_put_contents(LOCK_EX)` есть, а `file_get_contents (LOCK_SH)` не существует.

Если не нужно редактировать файл, а полностью перезаписывать, и старое содержимое файла не влияет на новое, то можно писать во временный файл и потом делать `rename` этого файла в нужное имя. 
При записи во временный файл с рэндомным именем нет конкурентного доступа, а `rename` атомарен.

При таком подходе никто не должен писать в конечный файл напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Файл 1.

```
<?php
function getConfig($full_path) {
   return (array());
}
```

Файл 2.

```
<?php
include('файл1.php');
$arr = getConfig($full_path);
if(!is_array($arr))...
```